# Why was a question closed quickly, without the OP being able to edit it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A question was recently placed online, called [Why did God allow both men and animals to eat flesh only after the flood and not after the fall?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/48528/21576)

It was quickly put on hold and never [closed], but soon deleted from the site. I'm curious because the suggestions said the OP had the right to edit his question to make it suitable for this site. Why would the OP be given that right and have it taken away? I thought any OP had the right to edit their questions to suit the site.

Thank you

Comment: @Nathaniel --thanks for the edit.

Comment: No problem!  Most users won't see anything when they click the link, but moderators and users with more than 10k rep will be able to view the  question and comments.

Comment: Even if you can't see the question, you'll see a notice saying the author deleted it.

Comment: I didn't see that notice but thank you

Comment: @Daisy: Telling people to "get a life" is not appropriate. Downvotes are allowed, and are actually encouraged. They also mean something entirely different on Meta than they do on the main site. If it bruises your ego to receive a downvote, this is going to be a very painful place for you.

Comment: Daisy ranting about downvotes inside of a post is inappropriate, nor are personal insults (even if the recipient is unidentified) appropriate. If you have a question about how voting should work or perhaps want tips on how to write better posts, please ask a question about that. In the mean time you should note that a valid reason for downvotes (as show my the message when you hover over the downvote button) is that it doesn't show any research effort or the question is not likely to be useful to others. In this case the information was on the page you were looking at, you just didn't read it.

Comment: No dear, the info was not on any page I was looking at. And if I want to post something on my post, I'll do it. If you want to delete it, delete it. People that down vote other people's questions here need to get a life. Period. Now you go ahead and delete this, Caleb.

Comment: @Flimzy The 404 page has a deletion reason and differs for deletion by owner and deletion by moderator. Check it yourself by logging out. It's not very bold, but it is there. Besides that detail, there are lots of other assumptions about the site and the way closures work that have been expained before to this user, I think some of the downvotes is likely frustration over the OP not having read the various help pages they've been pointed to.

Comment: Daisy if you want to post whatever you feel like you'll need to take it to your personal website to do that. This and all SE sites have guidelines for what you can and cannot post that are enforced by the community, the volunteer moderators, and the company behind the sites. You don't have the option to just disregard the way the community has agreed these sites should work.

Comment: People are asking questions, mainly for clarity on how to better use this site. This so-called "Christian" site. Yet, people are quick (and cowardly) to judge other people's questions. There's no intelligence or etiquette in judging someone else's questions for clarity. Someone could be older or even sick or disabled, and the people down voting wouldn't know. Clarification to understand this site better needs to be respected, not down voted. Especially at a "Christian" website. So yes, it's angered me into responding how I did because it's ignorant. If you don't like my response, delete it.

Comment: Regarding "so-called 'Christian' site" — please note, "[Brothers, we are not Christians‼](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/193/13677)" (the most upvoted question on this Meta site, indicating substantial community agreement).

Comment: @Susan This site should really be changed to About Christianity SE.  That actually fits.

Comment: @Adam Heeg, so clever and so true. There are other sites that might suit you better. I'm working on a project and no longer interested but I wanted to say that here, you were a breath of fresh air.

Comment: @Susan, I said "this so-called 'Christian site,'" which means exactly that -that I don't think it's a Christian site. It does not mean that I thought that  you or anybody else here is a Christian. That's an incorrect assumption. I don't see a consistent ethical pattern taking place on this site so I wouldn't assume it was "Christian." I was saying exactly what Adam says above. I think it would be a good idea, since you and others think people are misunderstanding you (I don't think they are), to state this on your Help Page. Also suggest not to assume.

Comment: Goodbye everybody. Signing off...

Answer (score 8):

The question was put on hold by David, as primarily opinion based. Then the OP deleted his own question, without any explanation, so I won't guess as to why the OP chose to delete rather than edit his question.

Answer (score 4):

The page you landed on showing the question was deleted explains all we know about the situation:

> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

Questions being put on hold quickly is normal and good. If a question has problems and needs to be edited it is better to close them until the edits are complete so that people don't waste time posting answers that might be deleted anyway. If the author chooses to edit them they can be re-opened.

In this case the author appears to have decided not to edit and deleted it instead. That's their prerogative and we don't require an explanation from them. Only after questions have answers does it require community or moderator approval to delete questions posts.